# Elm style-elements with dynamic style

Tags: css, elm, elm-style-elements

I have written a small dashboard using [Elm style-elements](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/mdgriffith/style-elements/4.2.1). Now I'd like to have one style property ([`Color.background`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/mdgriffith/style-elements/4.2.1/Style-Color#background)) to be determined based on a model property but I can't figure out how to do that (if it's possible at all).

I've written a [small sample app](https://ellie-app.com/Xdw59PJka1/1) using Ellie to show what I want to achieve. Below is a screenshot with the relevant details.

On line 48 I define a style with a bg color. The *red* component shouldn't be hard-coded but should come from the model. The model itself is just an `Int` that represents the amount of red.

[image]

Can this be done and if so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, just pass the model to the `stylesheet` function:

```elm
stylesheet : Model -> StyleSheet MyStyles variation
stylesheet model =
    Style.styleSheet
        [ Style.style PageStyle []
        , Style.style EltStyle [ Color.background (rgba model.red 128 128 255) ]
        , Style.style FieldStyle [ Color.border grey, Border.all 1 ]
        ]
```

You pass the `model` along like this:

```elm
view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    Element.layout (stylesheet model) <|
        ...
```

Comment: Ah, that's almost too easy :) I was trying to pass the model on the wrong level but this makes a lot more sense. I'll try this out.

Comment: Yup, `stylesheet` is just a function like any other, so it can accept arguments